Is it possible to burn tokens on transfer?
Hey is it possible to create a token2022, and burn x% of tokens on every transfer? Something like transfer tax, but burning the tokens. Also i got second question, how can i deploy token on-chain, cannot find any good guide for developing and publishing such program (token2022). Thank you.
(I would like to use JS)

Either build you own token extension, of just use transfer tax, and manually collect the transfer tax from user accounts at some interval of time and perform burn operation.

i can't even find any token sample code, could you give me any source? Also i read about transfer hook, functionality or smth - i could just burn tokens in it.

Yes, you can create a token with a burning mechanism in JavaScript:
Develop a token contract with a burn function that deducts a percentage of tokens from the sender's balance and reduces the total supply.
Modify the transfer function to include the burning mechanism.
Test your contract thoroughly.
Deploy your contract using tools like Anchor for Solana.
